# How do I echo this code that is part HTML part PHP?

Tags: php

I have a php page that includes a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'?Board=' . $_GET['Board']; ?>" method="post">
```

I now need to include that in an IF/THEN to modify the form action to either look like that or like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'?ADMIN=TRUE&Board=' . $_GET['Board']; ?>" method="post">
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to properly write the echo in my PHP given all the ' and "

```
<?php
    if($TheArg2 == "TRUE")
    {
        //The one with ADMIN would go here          
    }
    else
    {
        //The one without ADMIN would go here
    }
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Just do `$admin = $TheArg2 ? "ADMIN=TRUE&" : "";` Then use `$admin` in the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the url first then use it in form action

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?Board=".$_GET['Board'].($TheArg2 == true ? '&ADMIN=TRUE':'');
?>


<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="post">
```